# active record codeigniter update

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I run this code and I do not update

```
$sql="DATEDIFF(fecha_recepcion,now())";
$data=array('dias_restantes'=>$sql);
$this->db->where('estado',1);
$this->db->update('factura',$data);
```

I want to do something like

```
UPDATE `factura` SET `dias_restantes` = DATEDIFF(fecha_recepcion,now()) WHERE `estado` = 1
```

I want to do with Active Record of CodeIgniter.

Comment: Could you run `$this->db->_error_message();` immediately after `$this->db->update..` and tell us what, if any errors are returned? An example of the content you are trying to update would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $estado_id = 1; 
    $data = array(
                   'dias_restantes' => 'DATEDIFF(fecha_recepcion,now())'
                );
    $this->db->where('estado', $estado_id);
    $this->db->update('factura', $data);
```

Si quieres ver los errores, utiliza. $this->db->_error_message(); después de $this->db->update().

Te invito a que revises la página oficial.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `factura` SET `dias_restantes` = DATEDIFF(fecha_recepcion,now()) WHERE `estado` = 1 ");
```

Comment: This is not proper use of Active Record.